# Q: How to exclude persons name from a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use bigquery to find the 10 most mentioned persons in 4 Israeli news websites via gdeltv2 dataset. I succeded getting the 10 most mentioned persons and now I want to exclude two persons from the top 10 list, 'Maccabi Haifa ' and 'Reuben Castro '. I am using standardSQL bigqury code.

I created the dataset with this code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `top-reef-311415.56146_2021_Gad.israel_media` AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE
  SourceCommonName IN ('israelhayom.co.il',
    'ynet.co.il',
    'walla.co.il',
    'haaretz.co.il')
  AND LOWER(TranslationInfo) LIKE '%heb%';
```

And than used this code to create the 10 most mentions table excluding 'Maccabi Haifa ' and 'Reuben Castro ':

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `top-reef-311415.56146_2021_Gad.israel_media_person`
WHERE person <> 'Maccabi Haifa ' OR person <> 'Reuben Castro '
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

At the result table I still get a table with both of them. I will be greatful for the correct code to generate the expected results:

```
person          count_mentions  count_distinct_urls
Benjamin Netanyahu 33120         20768
Donald Trump       13787         7821
Gaza Gaza          13322         7654
Medinat Yisrael    12768         9148
Benny Gantz        10838         5736
Oz Muallem         10668         3891
Reuben Schwartz     9343         3644
Yedioth Ahronoth    8825         4491
Moshe Kahlon        8507         6537
Miri Regev          7915         4944
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `OR` with `AND` in `WHERE person <> 'Maccabi Haifa ' OR person <> 'Reuben Castro '`:

```
WHERE person <> 'Maccabi Haifa' AND person <> 'Reuben Castro'
```

Answer (score 2):

This may works:-

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
  `top-reef-311415.56146_2021_Gad.israel_media_person`
WHERE person NOT IN ('Maccabi Haifa', 'Reuben Castro')
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```